# how to close file descriptor bigger then 9 by dash in shell script

Tags: linux, file-descriptors, dash

I want launch a shell script in code called system("sh example.sh"), and close all file descriptors like this:

```
for fd in $(ls /proc/$$/fd); do
   case "$fd" in
    0|1|2)
        ;;
    *)
        eval "exec $fd<&-"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

but it report an error:
 `example.sh 1: exec: 10: not found`

the linux shell is dash, it seems that dash cannot operates file descriptors bigger then 9.
And I cannot access other linux shells like bash, what should I do to close the fds?
Thank you.

Comment: fds above 9 are reserved for the shell's own internal soup, you shouldn't touch them.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to run a shell in a separate process that closes all its fds?

Comment: I want to close the fds inherited from the parent process, like the tag O_CLOEXEC

Comment: This is completely impossible to do within dash alone.